# Laravel displaying errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've got some problems when I want to show validation errors when I got multiple forms on the same page.

As you can see below, I've got 2 forms (general and password) on the same page.

```
|        | GET|HEAD | profile/edit/settings          |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getEditSettings  | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | profile/edit/settings/general  |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@postEditSettings | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | profile/edit/settings/password |      | App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@postEditPassword | web,auth   |
```

Each form has a hidden input field like this:
`<input type="hidden" name="password2" value="1">`
and at the bottom of the view, I've got this:

```
@if (!empty(old('password2')))
        @include('errors.common')
@endif
```

This is so that I don't display the same errors on both forms.
**But no errors are showing whatsoever.**

And if I `dd(old('password2'))` I get `null`.

In my ProfileController I have this method:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 * Processing new password
 */
public function postEditPassword() {

    // Grab signed user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Change password
    $user -> changePassword(Input::all());

}
```

As you can see above, I try to change the password with my custom method in the User model, which looks like this:

```
public function changePassword($data) {

    // The signed user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Try to match the old password
    if (!Hash::check($data['old_password'], $user -> password)) {
        return redirect() -> back() -> with('error', 'Det gamle passordet stemmer ikke.');
    }

    // Validate the new password
    $validator = Validator::make([
        'password' => $data['password'],
        'password_confirm' => $data['password_confirm']
    ], [
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'password_confirm' => 'required|min:6|same:password'
    ]);

    if ($validator -> fails()) {
        return redirect() -> back() -> withErrors($validator);
    }

    // Change the password
    $user -> password = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user -> save();

    return redirect() -> back() -> with('success', 'Passordet ble endret!');

}
```

Also, besides the errors view problem, I was wondering if this is a good approach with processing different forms (take data in controller, send to model for processing and the model will then redirect).

Comment: No, if you're sticking with MVC, your model should definitely not be the guy to redirect to a view. Rather you should do data processing/retrieval related functions there. Also where is your errors.common view? To get non-null for password 2, you should also redirect `withInput()`

Comment: You are sending the password field more than once. So, the last one (empty) is rewriting the original field. Please share your view markup to put an eye. And definitively, the model is not intended to do any validation neither redirection.

Comment: I see. So just processing to return true/false. And then redirect from the controller, if I understand right?
Ah.. That's what I forgot.. `WithInput()`. Thanks!

@manix I tried changing the name of the field and `old()` value to the same. But didn't work, but I forgot the `WithInput()`. :)

Comment: Good catch! Just avoid focus logic in models.